# Call to a member function fetch_object() on a non-object

Tags: php

When I load the PHP page containing the code below I get the error "Call to a member function fetch_object() on a non-object." It pertains to the line starting with the word while. Why is this error popping up? **Ignore my security weaknesses please.**

PHP snippet:

```
header('Content-Type:application/json;charset=utf-8');

$file_absolute = "---placeholder for correct file path---";
include_once($file_absolute);
$mysql = new mysqli($db_host, $db_username, $db_password, $db_name);
$verb_value = $_POST['verb_value'];

$mysql->query("SET CHARACTER SET 'utf8'");

$result = $mysql->query("SELECT present_tense FROM $verb_value");

$queryResult = array();

while ($row = $result->fetch_object())
{
    $queryResult[] = $row->present_tense;
}
```

Comment: If `$result` isn't an object, then it's `FALSE` which is the return value of [`mysqli::query()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) when the statement fails. Also, is `$verb_value` really the name of your table?

Comment: @Hevelock I don't see anything wrong with my SQL query :( $verb_value is the PHP variable storing the value sent from the post method of my JQuery code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are lacking error checking in your code:

```
$result = $mysql->query("SELECT present_tense FROM $verb_value");
if( !$result)
  die($mysql->error);

$queryResult = array();

while ($row = $result->fetch_object())
{
    $queryResult[] = $row->present_tense;
}
```

The result of your query is a non object, but you did not check for that.

Note: your code is prone to SQL Injection: `$verb_value = $_POST['verb_value']` results in a possibility to inject SQL code into the database without checking!

Comment: I understand their are security weaknesses, and that's why I put in the question to ignore them so I could focus on the error message(s). When I add the error check from your code I get the error "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_OBJECT_OPERATOR" for the die line.

Comment: `die($mysql->error)` mysql is not a constant

Comment: @DavidBarker I've never used the die line. Are you saying the syntax is wrong?

Comment: @programm3r (Sorry David, wasn't meant for you ;)) because `die(mysql->error);` should be `die($mysql->error);`. Please do some checking for yourself when it comes to such obvious errors in PHP. You may need to search google, but all these errors have +5 years old topics, which for internet equivalents an age  ..

Comment: @dbf I misread David Barker's line. I thought he typed in the same line without the $ in it. That's why I was confused.

Comment: @programm3r The point that I think everyone is trying to make is, check for errors within your code and you won't have these problems in the future as you will be able to solve them with ease. This is a good answer, I was just correcting a small error.

Comment: I was under the impression there wasn't a typo, so that assumption in combination with me misreading David Barker's code led to my confusion and asking about whether the syntax is wrong. Yes, I do research and look things up, but sometimes it's unsuccessful. Need to keep in mind that just because answers to problems reside online doesn't mean everyone can always find where those answers are located.

Comment: please, do not forget to accept as answer

Answer (score 0):

```
$verb_value = $_POST['verb_value'];

$mysql = new mysqli($db_host, $db_username, $db_password, $db_name);

$mysql->query("SET CHARACTER SET 'utf8'");

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
       printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
       exit();
    }
$query = "SELECT present_tense FROM $verb_value";
$queryResult = array();
if ($result = $mysql->query($query)) {
  while ($row = $result->fetch_object()) {
     $queryResult[]=$row->present_tense;
  }
  $result->close();
 }
```