# Format using MYSQL Date Retrieved from Database and Display in PHP file

Tags: php, mysql

I am retrieving a date from my database. Now my assignment calls to format it using MYSQL.  I've tried using a similar call as I did to retrieve the data, but I keep getting the error message "Call to a member function fetch_object() on a non-object".

//RETRIEVE DATA FROM DATABASE INCLUDING $blog_date

```
  $db = new mysqli($host,$user,$pw,$database)
        or die("Cannot connect to MySQL.");

  $command = "select * from ".$table_name." where blog_id=".$blogId;
  $result = $db->query($command);
  while ($data = $result->fetch_object()) 
  {
    $blog_title = $data->blog_title;
    $blog_author = $data->blog_author;
    $blog_date = $data->date_of_blog;
    $blog_entry = $data->blog_entry;
  }
```

//Using MYSQL, I try to format $blog_date using the mysql date_format; however, I keep getting the error message "Call to a member function fetch_object() on a non-object"

```
  $command = "select date_format($blog_date, '%W, %m/%d/%Y') as formatted_date;";
  $result = $db->query($command); 
  while ($data = $result->fetch_object())
  {
    $blog_date_formatted = $data->formatted_date;
  }

  $db->close();
```

I appreciate your help!!!

Olive

Comment: possible duplicate of [Call to a member function fetch\_object() on a non-object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12552588/call-to-a-member-function-fetch-object-on-a-non-object)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error you are getting means that `$result` does not have a valid data from the database.

There is a problem with your `SELECT` statement. You need to specify from which database table you want to get the data. Something like this:

```
$command = "select date_format($blog_date, '%W, %m/%d/%Y') as formatted_date FROM table_name;";
```

More information on Mysql [SELECT Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html).

You can also add the following code before the `while` statement:

```
if (!$result) printf("Error message: %s\n", $mysqli->error);
```

This will print for you the error which is reported by the database.

Comment: Thanks @EcoG!! That worked perfectly. I noticed there was a second error in my select statement. I had forgotten to add quotes around my variable $blog_date like this.... 'code'   $command = "select date_format('".$blog_date."', '%W, %m/%d/%Y') as formatted_date FROM ".$table_name.";";   'code'